# Why is this conditional based on a non-distributive union type not working?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

I have an interface and want to determine if any of the values are optional. To do that, I thought I'd create a union out of all the values and then check if it extends `undefined`. When it didn't work, I read about distributive conditionals and thought surely that would be the solution.

Here's the code:

```js
export interface SomeInterface {
  someBool: boolean
  someOptionalNum?: number
  someOptionalText?: string
}

const test: [SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]] extends [undefined] ? boolean : string = true
```

According to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) part of the typescript guide, I would expect this code to work. But I can't get `test` to ever be a `boolean`, it remains stuck on `string`.

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQgFtgBJFNLXOAbwCg44BnY4AIQggBsAuOAI05dgmJA2asA8mBgIISTFwByAVyIB+PkjX804liWmz5igCqgYm5jCjIA5nQC+dOtnlN4qD3wDahEuSoGDjAPgDWwACeEOgErIGUIQC6SXAWwEgAJkxwPipZwOjIwJmp6gJCIkhwfB62SHZwALxwNirAQA)

Comment: Is there some deeper meaning to the distinction between `boolean` and `string` or are they just arbitrary outputs like "yes" vs "apple"?  (Like, why not `true` vs `false` or something?)

Comment: The issue with your code is that the conditional type you've written ([SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]] extends [undefined] ? boolean : string) is not distributive. Distributive conditional types distribute over union types, but in your case, you're passing a non-union type (SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]) as the input to the conditional type, so it won't be distributed.

Comment: What output would you like to see when?  You don't need to wrap `X[keyof X]` in a one-tuple because it's not a generic type parameter, so if you're trying to avoid distribution across unions it's already done.   Perhaps you are just looking for `undefined extends T[keyof T]` as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/N5AKPN), but that only detects that `undefined` is assignable to some property, and *not* whether they are optional.  So this looks like an XY problem.  How should we proceed here?  I'd love to have clarity around this.

Comment: @jcalz that was arbitrary, just for the example :)

Comment: @jcalz You are correct! It was not distributive and using `undefined extends X[keyof X]` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our understanding of the way extends works is causing the issue here.

[Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) take a form that looks a little like conditional expressions (condition ? trueExpression : falseExpression) in JavaScript:

```
  SomeType extends OtherType ? TrueType : FalseType;
```

> When the type on the left of the extends is assignable to the one on
> the right, then you’ll get the type in the first branch (the “true”
> branch); otherwise you’ll get the type in the latter branch (the
> “false” branch).

Take a look at this [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UBEBBJUA+yBCSDcAUKJFCgsmocdAJrlkQAewEAdgCYDOsUA-FMABOAV2gAuKADMAhgBtOEQkA) for example:

```
type X = "A" | "B";
type A = "A";
type Y = A extends X ? true : false;
```

Y would be true above.

In the question, `[SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]]` is not assignable to `[undefined]`. In fact, `[undefined]` is assignable to `[SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]]`.

So you have the conditions the other way round. You can change your code like:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  someBool: boolean
  someOptionalNum?: number
  someOptionalText?: string
}

const test: [undefined] extends [SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]]  ? boolean : string = true
```

and it should work.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=7&ssc=96&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQgFtgBJFNLXOAbwCg44BnY4AIQggBsAuOAI05dgmJA2asA8mBgIISTFwByAVyIB+PkjX804liWmz5igCqgYm5jCjIA5nQC+dOtnlN4qD3wDaKpAAmwOjIwAEAunAWwIFMcD6EJOSoGDjAPgDWwACeEOgErMmUaeGRcOoCQiJIcHwetkh2cAC8cDYqwC50oJCwiBSp1InAkjAAFmhFg3j0jAbsQnyC3NX6UjJyCspqWjp6c+vGW+YgMHU29k4ubkgebcAeAEy+-kEhSGGR0bHxw6MTUCmVHSWVy+T+40mA2BpUYFWWwlEtWsDSarQA5PV0UA)